# asp net core - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I have set two net core apps (netcoreapp2.0).

One is a net core webapi (backend app) that is responsible for returning data to the user. This app is running on http://localhost:5001

The other is a net core webapp(front end app) loading angular in index.cshtml. This app is running on http://localhost:5000

The problem i have is that after setting [Authorize] to my controllers in the api i get the **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** error

This is contained in the startup of the web api project:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ..................................

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowCredentials()
                               .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization", "WWW-Authenticate");
                    });
        });

        services
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddAuthorization();

        ..................................
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...................................

        app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        ...................................           

    }
```

Controller classes have:
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
where AllowAll is the name of the policy i set in startup above

Here is also the code in angular that returns the headers set in the requests:

```
getAuthHeaders(): Headers {
    if (this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Accept', '*/*');
        headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.oauthService.getAccessToken());
        return headers;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The preflight request is successful:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5001/api/Resource/data/el/Building
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Remote Address:[::1]:5001
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:access-control-allow-credentials,authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:5000
Date:Tue, 19 Sep 2017 09:55:27 GMT
Server:Kestrel
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcU3VuU29mdFxQTVNcc3Vuc29mdC5wbXNcU3VuU29mdC5QTVMuQVBJXGFwaVxSZXNvdXJjZVxkYXRhXGVsXEJ1aWxkaW5n?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-credentials,authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5001
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Referer:http://localhost:5000/list/Building
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

The actual request after that fails:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5001/api/Resource/data/el/Building
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:5001
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 19 Sep 2017 09:55:27 GMT
Server:Kestrel
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcU3VuU29mdFxQTVNcc3Vuc29mdC5wbXNcU3VuU29mdC5QTVMuQVBJXGFwaVxSZXNvdXJjZVxkYXRhXGVsXEJ1aWxkaW5n?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijg0YTI1NDQ0NmEyMWIwYWEwNTk0MjQwYmJiMzJiMmI1IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1MDU4MTMzODIsImV4cCI6MTUwNTgxNjk4MiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1NTU1IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1NTU1L3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IlNVTlNPRlQuUE1TLlNQQSIsInN1YiI6ImViY2JmNDcxLTZjMTgtNDczYS1iOWFkLWEyMzEwNTE5MjM4MyIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTUwNTgxMzM4MiwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwiZW1haWwiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.F7L06TWGiyXmZ8kZQBW3JDT_qaFyx3eQ_TafMLtpnBjUxPgKxKind_FUlNfGJufN-17HOW4tLVQljsH53z-a1N4JNOJ0YmlrnIGEWq3JGASnnqJPX2VUOjQR63JeRiwzs9LsTCngfSeHMrgAzEnDQRfw2lBU6Z3oN5iAu-1vE9yexLn009Ie-FVBscyZJkklTsMPJCuX6lO18_DGPRxhKlmhV3vVpNal97l0qh1DWdTd1Exb6Jye1svxyxUlonqj5oUT1JMMKpcW-9qvwB62bX8vG5_NaVdoaDu7RhntA9XinbLceIIat4V9O1hL9dYJKziB1MIJJrEynxci89AOLg
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:5001
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Referer:http://localhost:5000/list/Building
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

This is the message in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:5001/api/Resource/data/el/Building. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to decorate your controller with attribute [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:5000", headers: "*", methods: "*")] or [EnableCors("AllowAll")] to methods.

Comment: @Merchezatter I already have attribute [EnableCors("AllowAll")] on my Controllers where AllowAll is the name of the policy i set in startup. By the way EnableCors is only taking as a parameter the policy name. Thanks for the response anyway. I will also put this detail in my question above

Comment: Do you tried to use AllowAnyOrigin() instead WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000") ?

Comment: Makes no difference but when using authentication you can't use * for origin. You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is probably because an error occurred in the web API. Hence the `500` HTTP status code. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not present on the response because the error handling in ASP.NET Core clears the response headers, which results in an error in the browser.

Try to turn on exceptions/logging and diagnose what's causing the error in your web API.

Comment: You are right. I did put serilog and found a non relative error which lead to the misleading output in the console. Hope i have seen your answer before i wasted half a day looking at the wrong place.