# CORS asp.net core webapi - missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I have ASP.net WebApi Core with CORS enabled. It is Visual studio ASP.net Core Web API template. The only code added is code for CORS support:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddCors();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       /*  other stuff   */

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44310")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseMvc();
    }
        }
```

My API is hosted on localhost:**44361** and mycalling WEB on localhost:**44310**. There are different ports, so my request comes from different origin. Thats why there should be header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in response. It is missing and I see error in browser console:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44361/api/values' 
from origin 'https://localhost:44310' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Where is the problem?

Request headers:

```
GET https://localhost:44361/api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44361
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://localhost:44310
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://localhost:44310/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcQyNfcHJvZ3JhbW1pbmdcU0FNUExFU1xDb3JzQXBpU2ltdWxhdG9yXENvcmVBcGlcYXBpXHZhbHVlcw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 08:37:54 GMT
```

Comment: Everything within the question looks OK to me. Can you turn this into a [mcve]?

Comment: Is this happening also with `.AllowAnyOrigin()` ?

Comment: Yes, same result.

Comment: This is an outlier but will add my recent experience. 

In my case I added MFA requirements for accessing API resources. The API was throwing a 401 but this error cleared out the headers... hence no no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header was present. 
The point is that make sure you ensure no errors are present on your request before troubleshooting CORS

Answer (score 14):

can you try this one,

```
  services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

and use it

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

this code for any origins. I just had something like that , when i was using cors directly in app.UseCors() i had problem, then i tried this and it worked.
ps dont use app.UseCors() after app.UseMvc()

Comment: Having the host set as true means that it will allow any browser access this one. To limit this, replace `(host) => true` with `(host) => {return host == "my.domain.com";}` to allow just your trusted domain.

Comment: It has been 3 years and multiple versions of ASPNET.CORE, and this answer still finally stopped me from wanting to flip my desk. Similar to @GuybrushThreepwood, I recommend limiting the host to something you trust. For me, that was just localhost so my UI could hit my API from Chromium since no proxies I tried seemed to work because of UseHsts(). Testing all paths can be a pain :D

Answer (score 7):

This might occur because of a server-side error in which case the response headers gets cleared, clearing the CORS response headers as well. Try enabling exceptions and debug your application to find the error.

See also: [asp net core - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297242/asp-net-core-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-request/46306881#46306881).

Comment: I did not dig deep into logs, but my API is just pure web api project generated by Visual Studio with no additional code (except mentioned CORS). Response code is 200. I don't think its because of error.

Comment: Yup that was it. We're on .net 7 now and Microsoft still refuses to fix this telling me my API can't receive messages from my explicitly allowed origin. It makes zero sense considering a good application has an independent front and backend.

Answer (score 6):

This can occur if you have

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

in `Startup.Configure` and your development https certificate is not trusted by the browser. A call on the `http` endpoint will redirect to `https` which will then fail and return an error complaining about CORS headers.

Very frustrating to debug. Lost a morning to that one.